# How to add custom Antlr output path to main sourceset in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, antlr, antlr4

So, I'm new to Gradle and Java in general and having quite a few problems. Because of some other weird difficulties with IntelliJ, I want to change path that Antlr outputs the generated code to. This was easy to change:

```
generateGrammarSource {
    outputDirectory = file("src/temp/generated-code")
}
```

However, now I'm having great difficulty actually getting it to compile into my "main" and "test" source sets. I basically just want to extend the main and test source sets to include these files. I tried doing that with the something like:

```
sourceSets {
    generated{
        java {
            srcDir 'src/temp/generated-code'
        }
    }
    main {
        compileClasspath += generated.output
        runtimeClasspath += generated.output
    }
    test {
        compileClasspath += generated.output
        runtimeClasspath += generated.output
    }
}
```

However, doing this doesn't allow the generated code compilation to have access to the dependencies. So, compilation fails because it can't use all of the stuff in the antlr packages.

Is there any easy way to add these dependencies, OR, just force the main and test source sets to somehow include the generated code?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring this out in a deceptively easy way:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/java", "src/temp/generated-code"]
        }
    }
}
```

Though I did have to add this for proper clean up:

```
clean.doFirst {
    delete "src/temp"
}
```

I feel like there is probably a better way to do it than passing these path names around everywhere, but it seems to work fine